# Excel VBA Run time 53 file not found

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am using a macro to open latest file (downloaded from web service) from a folder and to save it from .xls to .xlxs for further operations.
The main operations (open latest and save it as.xlsx) are done, but the last line in the code gets this Runtime Error 53. Actually the re-saved under .xlxs file is there, but the macro gets this error. I don't know how to solve this since i am new to the VBA. Can i get some help, please :)
Here's the code i am using:

```
Sub TEST()

Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim LatestFile As String
Dim LatestDate As Date
Dim LMD As Date

MyPath = "C:\Downloads\Test"
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls", vbNormal)
If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
    If LMD > LatestDate Then
        LatestFile = MyFile
        LatestDate = LMD
    End If
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile

LatestFile = Left(LatestFile, InStrRev(LatestFile, ".") - 1)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=LatestFile, FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Kill LatestFile


End Sub
```

Comment: You removed the file extension from `LatestFile`. It'd probably be safer to use the full path as well.

Comment: Do a `msgbox(LatestFile)` to check if you have the correct filename just before the line that causes the error

Comment: @tnavidi - it doesn't do the trick - same error and file is already there with both the original and the re-saved files in the folder.
BigBen - the full path?
Also - if use the re-save macro as single, separate macro, it works perfectly, but combined with Open Latest File macro something is not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look carefully what you are doing with your filename(s).

After the loop finishes, `LatestFile` will contain the name of the latest file, without path.

You open that file - so far, so good.

Now you remove the extension from `LatestFile` and uses this as file name for the SaveAs command. **Here you have your first** issue because you don't provide any path. Excel will store the file where ever it guesses is right. This used to be the *current working directory*, but I am not sure this is valid any more. You should in any case provide the path.

Ok, file is saved. Now you want to delete the `xls`-version of the file. However, using `LatestFile` **now has 2 issues**: Firstly, you cut the extension, so you try to delete a file that has no extension (and that doesn't exist). And furthermore, you provide no path, so the kill-command looks in the *current working directory* (which is likely not the download folder).

```
Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
Dim newFileName As String
' (Change the following line if you want to save the copy to a different location)
newFilename = MyPath & Left(LatestFile, InStrRev(LatestFile, ".") - 1)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=newFileName, FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Kill MyPath & LatestFile
```

Hint: Learn to use the debugger, step thru the code and check what is going on. That helps you to understand your code and to see such problems.

Comment: Your patience is admirable.

Comment: A side suggestion for OP but a `Workbook` variable: `Dim wb As Workbook`, `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & LatestFile)`, then `wb` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`, might be better.

Comment: Thanks. I just cannot stand those answers that doesn't explain anything and just throw code. I was thinking about using a workbook variables but thought in this case it makes not much sense.

Comment: @FunThomas - thank you for the explanation that gives me the sequence of events! Really helpful to understand the process in depth!I don't have enough reputation point to give Useful answer :)
BigBen - thank you too; i started to wondering did i have to make this changes and you point me it's better. 
I will apply the changes and see how it works!